# Is it possible to detect when a PIP is opened in android using accessibility service?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I could not find any information or documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found it.

```
override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    /*
     * windows or getWindows() is an inherited property/function 
     * from AccessibilityService class.
     * Requires FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS meta-data
     */
    for (window in windows) {
        if (window.isInPictureInPictureMode){
             //Window is PIP
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should show where that windows variable comes from?

Comment: It's provided by the AccessibilityService class. `windows` or `getWindows()` (in Java) is a class property or method of AccessibilityService class.

Comment: It's not a static property/function

Comment: A comment addressed to you was just [posted as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77542660/5211833): "Does this solution works I've tested it few times and even when the PiP is on, the flag `isInPictureInPictureMode` returns `false`."

Comment: Yes for apps implementing PIP using the [native PIP api](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture#pip_button) .