# how to detect other app is in picture-In-picture mode or not in android kotlin

Tags: android, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I need to detect whether other apps are in Picture-In-Picture-Mode Or Not

I have already tried [Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226394/is-it-possible-to-detect-when-a-pip-is-opened-in-android-using-accessibility-ser) but not get intented output

is there any way we can detect other apps' pip modes?

**Note: **This app is not for Play Store, so we can get any permission from the user to get this output****

thanks in advance :)